# Collapse borders of div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to make following design.

[image]

I know this seems easy, but not with dynamic binding.

First of all grid tiles will be repeated dynamically (`v-for` of `vuejs` or `ng-repreat` of `angularjs`), so I can't use `table` and `rows`, I can only use `columns`.

So I have used `flexbox`, everything seems good, but **doubled borders** are creating issue.

I have tried this, but it won't work when there are less than 4 `cols` in a row.

```
.grid-table .row .col:nth-last-child(1),
.grid-table .row .col:nth-last-child(2),
.grid-table .row .col:nth-last-child(3),
.grid-table .row .col:nth-last-child(4) {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.grid-table .row .col:nth-child(4n) {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

**Question**: How can I collapse borders, and the solutions should be responsive too.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.grid-table {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.grid-table .row {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid-table .row .col {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 25%;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-table-tile .checkbox-custom {
  width: auto;
}

.grid-table-head .col.m12.s12 {
  height: 40px;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  flex: 1 1;
}

.grid-table .row .col:nth-last-child(1),
.grid-table .row .col:nth-last-child(2),
.grid-table .row .col:nth-last-child(3),
.grid-table .row .col:nth-last-child(4) {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.grid-table .row .col:nth-child(4n) {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-table">
  <div class="row grid-table-head">
    <div class="col m12 s12">Complaint Type</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col m3 s12">
      <div class="grid-table-tile">
        <div class="checkbox-custom">
          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="ctype-0" />
          <label for="ctype-0">Parking Issue</label>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-table-tile-title"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m3 s12">
      <div class="grid-table-tile">
        <div class="checkbox-custom">
          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="ctype-0" />
          <label for="ctype-0">Parking Issue</label>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-table-tile-title"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m3 s12">
      <div class="grid-table-tile">
        <div class="checkbox-custom">
          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="ctype-0" />
          <label for="ctype-0">Parking Issue</label>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-table-tile-title"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m3 s12">
      <div class="grid-table-tile">
        <div class="checkbox-custom">
          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="ctype-0" />
          <label for="ctype-0">Parking Issue</label>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-table-tile-title"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m3 s12">
      <div class="grid-table-tile">
        <div class="checkbox-custom">
          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="ctype-0" />
          <label for="ctype-0">Parking Issue</label>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-table-tile-title"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m3 s12">
      <div class="grid-table-tile">
        <div class="checkbox-custom">
          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="ctype-0" />
          <label for="ctype-0">Parking Issue</label>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-table-tile-title"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m3 s12">
      <div class="grid-table-tile">
        <div class="checkbox-custom">
          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="ctype-0" />
          <label for="ctype-0">Parking Issue</label>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-table-tile-title"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**[Dynamic demo with vuejs](https://jsfiddle.net/twt91h0d/)**

Comment: I see a table, not a flexbox. Please show your latest attempt with the double border problem.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware It's a table view but with using `flexbox`, I'm not using `table` because I can't use `tr`, anyways I have updated question, I hope it's bit clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope the below code helps.

In the css ,the below line matches the first element of the last row

**.grid-table .row .col:nth-child(4n+1):nth-last-child(-n+4)**

How means.for example n will 0,1,2 ...

so **.grid-table .row .col:nth-child(4n+1)** matches **1st** and **5th** element in our case.

when n is **0**

.grid-table .row .col:nth-child(4(0)+1):nth-last-child(-0+4) equates to

**.grid-table .row .col:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(4)**

first condition
**.grid-table .row .col:nth-child(1)** selects the **1** div

second condition
**.grid-table .row .col:nth-last-child(4)** selects the **4** div from last

since 1 & 4 is not the same element ,the condition fails

when n is 1;

.grid-table .row .col:nth-child(4(1)+1):nth-last-child(-1+4) equates to

**.grid-table .row .col:nth-child(5):nth-last-child(3)**

first-condition:**.grid-table .row .col:nth-child(5)** matches **5th** element

Second condition: **.grid-table .row .col:nth-last-child(3)** matches **3rd** element from last(which is actually 5th element from the first)

since the first & second condition pointing to the same element.

**.grid-table .row .col:nth-child(4n+1):nth-last-child(-n+4)** selects the 5th element.

the next line

**.grid-table .row .col:nth-child(4n+1):nth-last-child(-n+4) ~ .col** selects the elements after **5th** ie **6th** and **7th** in our case

In this way we can select the last row of the grid and remove border bottom

[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.grid-table {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.grid-table .row {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid-table .row .col {
  padding: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
  width: 25%;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-table-tile .checkbox-custom {
  width: auto;
}

.grid-table-head .col.m12.s12 {
  height: 40px;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  flex: 1 1;
}

.grid-table .row .col:nth-child(4n) {
  border-right: 0;
}

.grid-table .row .col:nth-child(4n+1):nth-last-child(-n+4),
.grid-table .row .col:nth-child(4n+1):nth-last-child(-n+4) ~ .col {
  border-bottom:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-table">
  <div class="row grid-table-head">
    <div class="col m12 s12">Complaint Type</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col m3 s12">
      <div class="grid-table-tile">
        <div class="checkbox-custom">
          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="ctype-0" />
          <label for="ctype-0">Parking Issue</label>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-table-tile-title"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m3 s12">
      <div class="grid-table-tile">
        <div class="checkbox-custom">
          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="ctype-0" />
          <label for="ctype-0">Parking Issue</label>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-table-tile-title"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m3 s12">
      <div class="grid-table-tile">
        <div class="checkbox-custom">
          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="ctype-0" />
          <label for="ctype-0">Parking Issue</label>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-table-tile-title"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m3 s12">
      <div class="grid-table-tile">
        <div class="checkbox-custom">
          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="ctype-0" />
          <label for="ctype-0">Parking Issue</label>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-table-tile-title"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m3 s12">
      <div class="grid-table-tile">
        <div class="checkbox-custom">
          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="ctype-0" />
          <label for="ctype-0">Parking Issue</label>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-table-tile-title"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m3 s12">
      <div class="grid-table-tile">
        <div class="checkbox-custom">
          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="ctype-0" />
          <label for="ctype-0">Parking Issue</label>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-table-tile-title"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m3 s12">
      <div class="grid-table-tile">
        <div class="checkbox-custom">
          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="ctype-0" />
          <label for="ctype-0">Parking Issue</label>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-table-tile-title"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

My simple solution use negative margin:

```
.grid-table .row .col {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    width: 25%;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
```